# Trying to insert 3gb delta hive table data into SQL Server Table using pyspark, but it is taking more than 9 hours to complete the Insertion

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have delta table Business_Txn with 3.1 GB data in it.
I am trying to write this data into SQL Server table but sometimes the Stages/Tasks take so much time.
Below is the code I am using:

```
df = spark.sql("select * from gold.Business_Txn")

try:
    df.write.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark").mode("overwrite").option("truncate", "false")\
      .option("url", azure_sql_url).option("dbtable", 'dbo.Business_Txn').option("user", username)\
      .option("password", password).option("bulkCopyBatchSize", 10000).option("bulkCopyTableLock", "true")\
      .option("bulkCopyTimeout", "6000000")\
      .save()
    print("Table loaded Successfully ")
except:
    print("Failed to load ")
```

My Cluster Config:

[image]

Can someone suggest changes so that my code utilizes cluster resources properly and make sql server table writes fast!

Comment: Check for blocking on the SQL Server.  Then use Profiler/XEvents to ensure that the Spark driver is properly performing bulk inserts, the client query will be "INSERT BULK" rather than "INSERT INTO".

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately I don't have control over SQL Server.

Comment: Then provision a new one to test with.

Comment: hi @Ramaraju.d, the above solution worked for you make it an answer it is useful to other community members.

Comment: Indeed, David's solution will work. But due to access constraints to client environment I couldn't test. I observed locks as well on the sql tables that could be another reason. The data in my Hive metastore is skewed that is another reason for the long waiting task. @DavidBrowne-Microsoft requesting you to post your comment as an answer.